# Cache data of remote database

Tags: database, caching, confluence

I have a Confluence website that uses a PostgreSQL database with one specific schema to store data. This website contains some scripts that query to a remote MySQL database to extracting data and generating a page with statistics to the user. To reduce the page’s load time, I have considered periodically extracting data from the remote database and storing this, already calculated and formatted, in the website’s machine.

Do you think that this strategy is correct?

What would be the best way to store this data? In the website’s database but in a different schema? In another separate database? In a text file? ...

Thank you for your help and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solve it developing my own Confluence plugin. This plugin have a job that runs periodically and generates an object that contains the generated statistics. This object is saved to the Confluence database, using [Bandana](https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/development-resources/confluence-architecture/confluence-internals/persistence-in-confluence). Finally, I have a Confluence page that retrieves the saved data and shows it to the user.

Answer (score 0):

have you considered Cache plugin?
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/org.swift.confluence.cache

Comment: Yes, webwesen, it is fantastic when the script shows the same information for all users, but otherwise not.